# Convert.ToDouble in c# not giving right answer when accessing redis database

Tags: c#

Im trying to convert a long string of numbers into a double in order to use that as an index to a redis database (redis requires a double) but the conversion isnt correct so the database fetch gets messed up.

Here is the code to convert the string into a double

```
string start="636375529204974172";
ulong istart = Convert.ToUInt64(start);   // result 636375529204974172
double dstart = Convert.ToDouble(istart); // result 6.3637552920497421E+17
```

as you can see the problem starts when i convert istart to a double as dstart, some of the least significant digits gets messed up, seems by the conversion introducing the E+17 in there.

I cant understand why, its a WHOLE NUMBER, no fractional part to create error so why it cant do it?

Does anybody knows how to fix the conversion from a string to double?

Comment: i thought so too, but double goes to E+308 while im just using E+17 so it should work right?

Comment: Try using `Decimal` it's more precise

Comment: Why is decimal more precise the double?

Comment: @jdweng - it is a 128 bit data type.     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal

Comment: cant use decimal because the database function call needs double, it uses the double value to start returning data indexed by that value in the database, right now its skipping lots of values because the number is wrong, messing up the whole program

Comment: "I thought so too, but double goes to E+308 while im just using E+17 so it should work right" - `double` has a huge *range*, but that doesn't mean it has 308 digits of *precision*.

Comment: the number im giving it is a WHOLE number, there is no fraction, so why is it changing the whole number to something else?

Comment: @PaulMan: It isn't. It's giving you a whole number: 636375529204974210. It's just representing that in scientific notation.

Comment: There is nothing "decimal" in `float` and `double`. The representation is binary, the base is 2, and the point is floating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cant understand why, its a WHOLE NUMBER, no fractional part to create error so why it cant do it?

Because it still only has 64 bits of information to play with, 52 of which are used for the mantissa, 11 of which are used for the exponent, and 1 of which is used for the sign.

Basically you shouldn't rely on more than 15 decimal digits of precision in a `double`. From the [docs for `System.Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.7):

> All floating-point numbers also have a limited number of significant digits, which also determines how accurately a floating-point value approximates a real number. A Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

The first 15 significant digits of your value *are* correct - nothing is going wrong here. The nearest `double` value to your original value is exactly 636375529204974208. There *is* no `double` that precisely represents 636375529204974172.

Comment: theres always something to mess things up, my whole program was using that

Comment: The solution i came up with was to subtract the number of ticks of Jan 1, 2017 from the current datetime ticks, this created a smaller tick size, then i used that  instead

Comment: @PaulMan: If you're dealing with ticks, can't you use an integer type instead? Or does Redis only support floating point values?

Comment: Redis only takes double unfortunately